# Need to force IE11 to IE7 using X-UA-Compatible

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

When I kept the tag meta tag 'meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"' in header tag of my jsp, but jsp is in under nested of another jsp like showed in the image.
But i cannot kept in the above jsp, because it's controlled by some other team.

I need to force the Internet explorer to IE7 could someone help me to this without change in system properties
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be impossible as of IE9 - from [How Internet Explorer Chooses Between Document Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803(v=vs.85).aspx) (emphasis added):

> 2. In Internet Explorer 9, if the document is hosted in an iframe element, the document mode is determined by the document mode of the
>      top-level webpage. **Subdocuments cannot be rendered in IE9 mode unless
>      the top-level document is also in IE9 mode.**

I would assume this rule also applies to framesets - and different document modes - as in your case.

For a more recent look at how IE11 decides which document mode to render in, take a look at [Deprecated document modes and Internet Explorer 11](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/deprecated-document-modes), which contains a flowchart of the process.